# extract gnome gconf settings from external partition

Tags: gnome, command-line, backup, gconf, restore

Are there any files in /etc/ or /home/ where the gconf data is actually written to? How can I make these work on a new system (preferably in terminal)?

There are standard ways dumping/importing gconf settings in a working distribution; mine is dead now - I'd like to backup/restore the old settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question you want to copy settings from old system to the new one. In my backup scripts I just copy `~/.gconf` directory which store all the settings configurable with `gconf-editor`. That works for me.

There are other directories for settings of your GNOME desktop environment which you may want to copy:

- `~/.config` - contains config files for applications (default location for the environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME).
- `~/.gnome2` - user-specific application data that is not stored in the GConf repository.
- `~/.local/share` - default location for the environment variable XDG_DATA_HOME.
- `~/.fonts` - fonts that you installed.
- `~/.nautilus` - contains file manager data that is specific to the user. For example, this directory can contain the following:

  - Metadata for the directories with which the user works.
  - Nautilus emblems that the user adds.
  - Nautilus desktop images.
- `~/.themes` - contains your (not system-wide) themes

Comment: so practically everything sits in homedir?

Comment: @troyaner Yes. That is why it called home dir. All user files and setting stored in one place. You shouldn't care about other directories if you did not make any changes outside your home dir.

Comment: I did, but that's another story ;) ok, thx!

Comment: The directory `~/.gconf` doesn't exist on my system (Ubuntu 22.04.3).